# How to have a text label on links in d3 force directed graphs

Tags: d3.js, label

I am using a force directed graph, and i would like to have the text on the link centred on the link (see image). Is there a way to do it ?

[image: Click here to see how I want the labels to be shown]

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have checked that post. Thats not what I want. Firstly , in that the text is for links that are fixed. Secondly, I want the text to be on the line of the link, as shown in the screenshot I have posted

Comment: The solutions described there should also be applicable in your case -- putting the text on the line should only require a `dy` adjustment. It would help if you could post some code that shows what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 11):

I believe Lars is correct. Based on the last response from the link he provided, I added this code to one of my force graphs and it worked fine:

```
var path = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("id",function(d,i) { return "linkId_" + i; })
    ...

var labelText = svg.selectAll(".labelText")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("text")
    .attr("class","labelText")
    .attr("dx",20)
    .attr("dy",0)
    .style("fill","red")
  .append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href",function(d,i) { return "#linkId_" + i;})
    .text(function(d,i) { return "text for link " + i;});
```